# ¿Cómo fusionar dos autómatas?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quiero crear un supervisor autómata. He podido crear la clase de autómatas. Sin embargo, cuando me enfrento a la caja de la fusión con los autómatas, no sé cómo manejarlos. Por ejemplo con los siguientes autómatas:

[image]

Los datos que estoy usando son

```
donnees=("nomprob", # nombre del problema
        [("e1",True),("e2",True),("e3",True),("s1",False),("s2",False),("s3",False)], # events
        ("plant",[("S4",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], # primeros estados autómata
            [("S4","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e3"]),("S1","S4",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])]), # transiciones de 1ero autómata
        ("spec",[("S0",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], #estados de segundos autómata
            [("S0","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S0",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])] # transiciones de 2ndo autómata
        )
    )
```

Y el método que estoy modificando para crear un autómata marcado es:

```
def creerplantspec(self,donnees):
    """Método para crear los autómatas sincronizados.

    Args:
        donnees (:obj:`list` of :obj:`str`): Nombre, eventos, transición y estados de los autómatas de sincronización.

    Attributes :
        plantspec (Automate): Autómatas de especificaciones que queremos crear con un nombre dado, eventos y estados.
    """
    nom,donneesEtats,donneesTransitions=donnees
    self.plantspec=Automate(nom,self)
    for elt in donneesEtats :
        nom,initial,final=elt

        (self.spec+self.plant).ajouterEtat(nom,initial,final)
    for elt in donneesTransitions:
        nomDepart,nomArrivee,listeNomsEvt=elt
        self.spec.ajouterTransition(nomDepart,nomArrivee,listeNomsEvt)
```

El código completo se puede encontrar [en github](https://github.com/antoinecomp/automata_synchronization/blob/master/README.md).
Ya pensé en este algoritmo:

```
for (Etat_s, Etat_p) en planta, espec.
         creamos un nuevo estado Etat_ {s.name, p.name}
         for (transition_s, transition_p) en Etat_s, Etat_p:
             Nuevo estado con la concatenación de los nombres de los extremos de las transiciones.
             Si los eventos de transiciones son los mismos:
                 agregamos una transición de Etat_ {s.name, p.name} a este último estado
             más si las transiciones son diferentes
                 aqui no se
```

Estoy comprobando las ideas de aplicar de-morgan en eso [de lo que he hablado aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201643/how-to-merge-two-finite-state-automata). Pero nunca lo implementé. De todos modos estoy abierto a cualquier fusión de ideas.

#### Código mínimo construyendo los autómatas:

Si lo necesitas aquí está el código. Construye los autómatas pero no los fusiona todavía (y lo siento por el francés :)):

```
    def creerplantspec(self,donnees):
        """method to create the synchronised automata.

        Args:
            donnees (:obj:`list` of :obj:`str`): name, events, transition and states of the synchronisation automata.

        Attributes :
            plantspec (Automate): automata of specifications we want to create with a given name, events and states.
        """
        nom,donneesEtats,donneesTransitions=donnees
        self.plantspec=Automate(nom,self)
        for elt in donneesEtats :
            nom,initial,final=elt

        for elt in donneesTransitions:
            nomDepart,nomArrivee,listeNomsEvt=elt
            self.spec.ajouterTransition(nomDepart,nomArrivee,listeNomsEvt)

    # we're going to synchronize
    def synchroniserProbleme(self):
        # we're saving the states of both
        etat_plant = self.plant.etats
        etat_spec = self.spec.etats
        # we create the automaton merging  plant and spec automata
        self.plantspec = Automate("synchro",self)
        print self.evtNomme
        # then we synchronize it with all the states
        for etat_p in etat_plant:
            for etat_s in etat_spec:
                self.synchroniserEtats(etat_p, etat_s, self) 


    def synchroniserEtats(self, etat_1, etat_2, probleme):
        # we're adding a new state merging the given ones, we're specifying if it is initial with all and final with any
        print str(etat_1.nom + etat_2.nom)
        self.plantspec.ajouterEtat(str(etat_1.nom + etat_2.nom), all([etat_1.initial,etat_2.initial]), any([etat_1.final, etat_2.final]))

        # 
        for transition_1 in etat_1.transitionsSortantes:
            for transition_2 in etat_2.transitionsSortantes:
                self.plantspec.ajouterEtat(str(transition_1.arrivee.nom+transition_2.arrivee.nom), all([transition_1.arrivee.nom,transition_2.arrivee.nom]), any([transition_1.arrivee.nom,transition_2.arrivee.nom]))
                # we're going to find the subset of the events that are part of both transitions
                evs = list(set(transition_1.evenements).intersection(transition_2.evenements))
                # we filter the names 
                evs = [ev.nom for ev in evs]
                # 
                self.plantspec.ajouterTransition(str(etat_1.nom+etat_2.nom),str(transition_1.arrivee.nom+transition_2.arrivee.nom), evs)

donnees=("nomprob", # name of the problem
        [("e1",True),("e2",True),("e3",True),("s1",False),("s2",False),("s3",False)], # events
        ("plant",[("S4",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], # first automata states
            [("S4","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e3"]),("S1","S4",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])]), # first automata transitions
        ("spec",[("S0",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], #second automata states
            [("S0","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S0",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])] # second automata transitions
        )
    )



nom,donneesEvts,donneesPlant,donneesSpec=donnees

monProbleme=Probleme(nom)

for elt in donneesEvts:
    nom,controle=elt
    monProbleme.ajouterEvenement(nom,controle)


monProbleme.creerPlant(donneesPlant)
monProbleme.plant.sAfficher()

monProbleme.creerspec(donneesSpec)
monProbleme.spec.sAfficher()

# my attempt
monProbleme.synchroniserProbleme()

# visualise it
# libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build a dataframe 

print monProbleme.plantspec.transitions

fro =  [transition.depart.nom for transition in monProbleme.plantspec.transitions if len(transition.evenements) != 0]
to = [transition.arrivee.nom for transition in monProbleme.plantspec.transitions if len(transition.evenements) != 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':fro, 'to':to})

print fro

print to

# Build your graph
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to')

# Plot it
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

And when run it gives back :

[image]

Que no es realmente lo que esperaba ...